# laravel migration took too long for every migrate

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

normally every migration took about 20~50ms, of course it depend on system resource and configs but when I run `php artisan migrate(or :fresh)` it took about about 2000~10000ms for every migration file!
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 5.19.0-46-generic
Shell: zsh 5.8.1
CPU: Intel i7-4800MQ (8) @ 3.700GHz
Memory: 31997MiB
Mysql: 8.0.33
php: 7.4

I tried this configs for mysql but nothing happend.

```
max_binlog_size   = 100M
innodb_io_capacity = 2000
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

[image]

Comment: your database is in same server or in different place?

Comment: @ariful-islam yes it is in same server on my local pc